# dynamically added div is not draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make my dynamically added divs draggable but if I call after

```
$("#draggable").draggable({});
```

this

```
for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
  var smallone = document.createElement('div');
  smallone.id = "draggable";
  smallone.className = "smallDiv";
  smallone.style.bacgroundColor = 'blue';

  document.body.appendChild(smallone);
}
```

there is no chance to make divs draggable.
I know it works if i create divs first but I need to keep it like this because of my project and this example shows my problem.
Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/9jstfwpm/4/

Thank you in advice.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9jstfwpm/5/

Comment: You generally have to call the `draggable` plugin again, to initialize it on the newly added elements.

Comment: @RayonDabre I feel terrible, its so easy thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to `initialize` `draggable` widget after appending new element.

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jstfwpm/9/):

```
for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  {
      var smallone = document.createElement('div');
      smallone.id = "draggable";
      smallone.className = "smallDiv";
      smallone.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      document.body.appendChild(smallone);      
      $(smallone).draggable({});
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead of id as id must be unique

```
$(".draggable").draggable({});
```

Assign draggable class to all divs

Answer (score 0):

simple 1 ...

```
for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
  var smallone = document.createElement('div');
  smallone.id = "draggable";
  smallone.className = "smallDiv";
  smallone.style.bacgroundColor = 'blue';

  document.body.appendChild(smallone);
  $(".smallDiv").draggable({});
}
```

it is working...     http://jsfiddle.net/9jstfwpm/7/

Comment: How about `$(smallone).draggable({});` ? ;)

Comment: @RayonDabre what does it mean that "it will make elements draggable multiple times" ?

Comment: correct you can also try like this,  no conflicts,,,

`smallone.id = "draggable"+i;   `  
 and 
 `$("#"+smallone.id).draggable({});`

Comment: I am not certain about the harm but consider it this way, If the element is draggable then why to reinitialize it as draggable again. `$(".smallDiv")` will select all the elements having class as `smallDiv` not the earlier appended element. We just have to attach event to new element..

Comment: u r right , U can put that outside the loop.. but any ways `$(smallone).draggable({});` is also wrking....